# function import in entity framework

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

As the MSDN says

```
    Do one of the following from the Model Browser:

    Open the Stored Procedures folder (in the storage model information) and double-click a stored procedure that does not have a corresponding function import.

- OR -

    Right-click the Function Imports folder (in the EntityContainer node of the conceptual model information) and then select Add Function Import.

The Add Function Import dialog box appears.
```

How can I do function import if my db contains **hundreds of sps**. Should I go to each sp and do the steps above :( .. It makes no sense.

Comment: You could always hand-edit the EDMX file :)

Comment: @Hightechrider :- So how it makes easy to programmers. They select each and every and repeat the same ??????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a very large Entity Framework model and I use the [Huagati DBML/EDMX](http://www.huagati.com/dbmltools/) tools.  It was able to bulk add new tables, views and columns that were in the database but not in the EDMX.  It saved a lot of manual work.  I haven't used it for stored procedures but it looks like it supports it.  Even better, they have a free trial so you can always give it a try to see if it will work for you.

**Edit**:  It also sounds like they have made some improvements to this in the latest version of EF - the June 2011 CTP.  [This blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/announcing-the-microsoft-entity-framework-june-2011-ctp.aspx) states:

> There are several new features for the Entity Framework Designer
> within Visual Studio:
>
> - [...]
> - When you import stored procedures using the Entity Model Wizard,
>   you
>   can now batch import your stored procedures as function imports.
>   The
>   result shape of each stored procedure will automatically become a
>   new
>   complex type in your entity model. This makes getting started with
>   stored procedures very easy.

If you don't want to use a CTP, [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/08/11/next-ef-release-plans.aspx) says they might have the official version out next month.